# What is a PEG Buffer Length?

Tags: memory, bios, desktop-computer

Since no one is helping me on my previous question, I'm scavenging my BIOS:

What is the PEG Buffer Length?
I tried looking at my computers manual but it informs me that it is infact:
A PEG Buffer Length.

Seeing how my manual is helping me ***so much***, does anyone know what it is?

Le Manuel: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/socket775/P5W%20DH%20Deluxe/e2557_p5w_dh_dlx.pdf

Page: 4-26 (No its not between 4-26, thats just how the pages are labeled)

Motherboard: P5W DH Deluxe {ASUS}

BIOS: V3001 [Latest from ASUS] {ASUS}

Memory: 2gb x 4 [DDR2 PC-6400 ; 800 Mhz ; 200 pin] {The manufacture doesn't label the ram}

Storage: 1TB {Toshiba}

Graphics Card: EVGA GTX 650 (Super Clocked Edition) {NVidia}

Monitor (If it matters): 1920x1080 SyncMaster S24B150

Answer (score 1):

The is the number of writes from the GPU to main memory that can be accumulated before a write operation to memory starts. There's no reason I can imagine to ever change the default. Smaller/shorter settings give very slightly higher graphics performance at the cost of very slightly worse memory latency for the CPU.